# Why cannot apply style using CSS class in JS function?

Tags: javascript, css

In this code the function sayHi() doesn't write text with style.  Why?
How do I apply CSS class to a document.write in a function?

```css
.class1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.write("<h1 class=class1>Hello World</h1>");

  function sayHi() {
    document.write("<h1 class=class1>Goodbye!</h1>");
  }
</script>

<button onclick="sayHi()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `document.write` used that way (in an event) has side effects that result in the style being lost ... so ... `document.write` is old old school, and should never be used, *except maybe in inline code that runs during page load*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.write` is `document.wrong` - whenever you use it after the page has been loaded, it replaces the *whole* page with the new HTML string. That's pretty much never a good idea. In this case, it's replacing the page *including your CSS*, so there's no `style` to apply to the `class1`.

Use proper DOM methods instead:

```js
  function sayHi() {
    const h1 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1'));
    h1.className = 'class1';
    h1.textContent = 'Goodbye!';
  }
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=class1>Hello World</h1>
<button onclick="sayHi()">Click me</button>
```

Or, if you want to remove the existing elements first (but *not* the `style`), clear `document.body`:

```js
  function sayHi() {
    document.body.textContent = '';
    const h1 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1'));
    h1.className = 'class1';
    h1.textContent = 'Goodbye!';
  }
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=class1>Hello World</h1>
<button onclick="sayHi()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `whenever you use it` - simplistic - during initial page load it does not :p

Comment: `document.write is document.wrong` - I'm using that from now on :p

Comment: If that is the case then how initially the `document.write` is writing 'Hello' without removing the button element and also the style element